# Nested Script Tags, Comparison of 2 Approaches

Tags: javascript

To avoid the premature closing of the first script tag in the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script>');
</script>
```

from I've read, two common approaches (I know there are others as well) are:

OPTION 1: Escape the forward slashes in the nested script:

```
document.write('<script type="text\/javascript" src="file.js"><\/script>');
```

OPTION 2: Break apart the word "script" in the nested script:

```
document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');
```

Am I correct in that both options are acceptable?

The first approach seems simpler, but I guess if there several lines of code in the nested script, the second approach might be less cumbersome than escaping a multitude of forward slashes (or quotation marks)?

EDIT: I'm mentioning these two options instead of document.createElement('script'); because I'm comparing approaches that are versatile enough to handle other nested javascript examples as well. For example, something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (/iPhone/).test(navigator.userAgent)
{
  document.write('<script type="text/javascript">');
  document.write('function myFunction () {');
  // Some stuff for iPhone
  document.write('}');
  document.write('myFunction();');
  document.write('</script>');
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

> OPTION 1: Escape the forward slashes

No. You don't need to escape all forward slashes. You only need to break apart the `</script>` tag somehow, and the standard approach is to but a backslash right after the opening `<`.

So use just

```
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"><\/script>');
```

(and of course if you're not doing anything dynamic like computing the url or loading the script only optionally, there's no reason to "nest" script elements at all, just put it statically right into your document)

Comment: I didn't realize that it wasn't necessary to escape all forward slashes. I have seen quite a few examples where all forward slashes were escaped (similar to the way all quotations marks were escaped), but perhaps they are older examples.

Comment: @KenBoone: Or perhaps their authors didn't understand what they were doing :-) Only in regex literals (where they are delimiters) you need to *escape* forward slashes.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to load the script but don't care if it is loaded synchronously or asynchronously, a much cleaner alternative is to `createElement`:

```
var sc = document.createElement('script');
sc.setAttribute('src', 'file.js');
sc.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
document.head.appendChild(sc);
```

This approach will load asynchronously, whereas yours will do so synchronously.

Comment: This does not do the same thing as the OP's code.  While both add the script to the page, the OP's code adds it synchronously, while this adds it async.

Comment: @jfriend00 - that's true... it also doesn't add it "in place", and adds it as a last element in the head. All that said, if one wants to add a script to a page, this is a typical method to do so, so I thought it's a relevant answer.

Comment: Yes, this is one of other ways I had mentioned seeing and works for the example I gave. I should have mentioned it, but I wanted to compare approaches that would handle ALL instances of nested script tags, not just ones where you are referencing a js file.